# Subdirectories for html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, subdirectory

I want to be able to test my html file using "someDirectory/someHTML.html/someSubDirectory"
Is there a way to implement this without using the div tag and javascript?

The best I got to this was using hidden div tags, javascript, and a div tag with the id of screen by just changing the innerHTML variable of the screen div tag to the innerHTML variable of the current page's div tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <style>
      .page {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    <p id="display">
      Current page:
      p1
    </p>
    <div id="screen"></div>
    <div id="page1" class="page">
      <!--- Page one code instead of button --->
      <button type="button" onclick="nav('p2')">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" class="page">
      <!--- Page two code instead of button --->
      <button type="button" onclick="nav('p1')">Don't click me</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      var currPage = 'p1';
      var disp = document.getElementById('display');
      var screen = document.getElementById('screen');
      var pages = {
        p1:document.getElementById('page1'),
        p2:document.getElementById('page2')
      };
      function nav(page) {
        screen.innerHTML = pages[page].innerHTML;
        currPage = page;
        disp.innerHTML = `Current page:\n${page}`;
        console.log('showed '+page);
      }
      nav('p1');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only thing is that it is EXTREMLY inefficient and I just want to use a slash

Comment: What do you mean with subdomain? In `www.stackoverflow.com` the subdomain is `www`, see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain)

Comment: @jabaa sry I missread the article I was reading [here](https://callnerds.com/parts-of-a-link-url-explained) and it's actually subdirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a hash (`#`) do instead of a slash (`/`) in the address bar?

That would fit your needs if those are that you whish to have only one HTML file located on your hard drive. The address bar would look like `c://users/AverseMoon/myHTMLpage.html#page2`.

You can show/hide any div with it using a hash in the adresse bar. *(A subdomain really is somthing else)*.

It would look like this:

```js
// The current page display
var disp = document.getElementById('display');

// The hashchange event handler
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {

  // Update display
  let currentHash = location.hash
  disp.innerHTML = "Current page: " + currentHash.substring(1)

  // Hide all .page
  document.querySelectorAll(".page").forEach(function(page) {
    page.style.display = "none";
  })
  
  // Show the current page
  document.querySelector(currentHash).style.display = "block";
})


// Page1 visible on load
document.getElementById('page1').style.display = "block";
```

```css
.page {
  display: none;
}
.page a{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: lightgrey;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p id="display">
  Current page: page1
</p>

<div id="page1" class="page">
  <a href="#page2"> Go to page #2</a>
</div>
<div id="page2" class="page">
  <a href="#page1"> Go to page #1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Trying it right now. Do you know of a better html, css, javascript editor no admin install that is better than Notepad++

Comment: Is there a way you could compress this down with the <script> and <style> tags??

Comment: Also you forgot semicolons in 2 lines of your js code

Comment: I did have to make a small edit to get it to work because I'm going to embed tons of code.org app lab and game lab projects.

Comment: About a better editor than Notepad++ (which I love), I would suggest [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/). I use both actually, depending on the task.

Comment: About compression... No. But you may mean [minification](https://www.minifier.org/).

Comment: I found a different one actually, called RJ TextEd which is pretty dang good

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to load page contents dynamically so you can use AJAX. create your index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <a href="/index.html"> <button id="index">Page 1</button></a>
        <button id="page2" onclick="loadPage(this)">Page 2</button>
        <button id="page3" onclick="loadPage(this)">Page 3</button>
    </nav>
    <p id="display">
        Contents from page 1
    </p>
    <script>
        function loadPage(p) {
            let URL = "./" + p.id + '.html';
            let Container = document.getElementById("display");

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    Container.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }

                
                console.log('Request send')
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", URL, false);
            xhttp.send();

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Then create the files you want to load the contents in index.html

Page1.html

```
<h1> Contents from page 1.</h1>
<p> Your paragraphs here</p>
```

Page2.html

```
<h1> Contents from page 2. </h1>
<p> Your paragraphs for page 2 are written here. </p>
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to pay for a website and I just want to share it with friends without hosting on my pc and giving them my ip because then they might share it to their friends and then I get a DDoS attack one file with all external data like images on gdrive I can just send the file and I'm good.

Comment: But still thanks for the help. If I make a huge website totally yes I will use this!

Comment: Just for a clearance. Do you want to use your computer to show your friends your html files or some website like Google.com but through your computer?

Comment: I want to show them a small html project, all dependencies are on google drive I just don't want to share my IP address with them.

Comment: create a 100% free website here no payment and no banner. https://infinityfree.net/

Comment: I'll try it out right now.